# RSA private Key decryption giving "InvalidCipherTextException" using bouncy castle

Tags: java-me, rsa, bouncycastle

I am creating a encryption/decryption method using bouncy castle for j2me. I have created private / public keys using openssl and hard coding into the code. Encryption is working fine (I am getting encrypted string), but when I try decryption for that ciphertext I am getting below exception

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: unknown block type
 - org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.decodeBlock(PKCS1Encoding.java:362)
 - org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.processBlock(PKCS1Encoding.java:166)
 - com.ust.CryptoJ2me.RSADecrypt(CryptoJ2me.java:564)
```

PFB the code snippet

```
public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] toEncrypt) throws Exception {
    String cipherStr;
    String modStr ="AA878F0D9........";
    String expStr = "10001";
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(modStr,16);
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(expStr,16);
    System.out.println("modulus = "+modulus+"// exponent = "+exponent);
    RSApubKey = new RSAKeyParameters(false,modulus,exponent);

    if (RSApubKey == null)
        throw new Exception("Generate RSA keys first!");

    AsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new RSAEngine();
    eng = new PKCS1Encoding(eng);
    eng.init(true, RSApubKey);
    byte[] cipherByte = eng.processBlock(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.length);
    return cipherByte;//cipherStr;
}

public String RSADecrypt (byte[] toDecrypt) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("toDecrypt = "+toDecrypt);
    //byte[] toDecByte = toDecrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
    //System.out.println("toDecByte ="+toDecByte);
    String plainText;
    BigInteger RSAmod = new BigInteger("00d1aec38b8d189a0a1..",16);
    BigInteger RSAprivExp  = new BigInteger("2d7af1b1283688dadc16..",16);
    BigInteger RSApubExp = new BigInteger("10001",16);
    BigInteger RSAdp = new BigInteger("00f5847cc67ea018f10f16..",16);
    BigInteger RSAdq = new BigInteger("00daa299bf356c6c6db6a21..",16);
    BigInteger RSAp = new BigInteger("00e28dd601e878dd6b1c0c..",16);
    BigInteger RSAq  = new BigInteger("400ff2e2df018507e4c2be6..",16);
    BigInteger RSAqInv   = new BigInteger("00cf4b2ba101efb2378aee..",16);
    RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters RSAprivKey = new RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters(RSAmod, RSApubExp,
            RSAprivExp, RSAp, RSAq, RSAdp, RSAdq, RSAqInv);

  AsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new RSAEngine();

  eng = new PKCS1Encoding(eng);

  eng.init(false, RSAprivKey);
  byte[] plainByte = eng.processBlock(toDecrypt, 0, toDecrypt.length);
  plainText = new String(plainByte);

  return plainText;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulus doesn't match between public key and private key. It should match. The private key modulus is probably smaller (assuming big endian notation and same length hex strings) and that is why you're getting this error message. Since the private key contains the modulus and public exponent components, you can replace them in the encryption code and see if the decryption works with a new ciphertext.

RSA works by raising some message to a power *e* (public exponent) modulo *m*. This results in ciphertexts that are smaller than *m*, but close to it. The decryption works by raising the ciphertext to the power of *d* (private exponent) modulo *m* (the same modulus).

If the private key modulus is much smaller than the public key modulus, the ciphertexts will be bigger and it cannot be decrypted. Mathematically it is possible to "decrypt" the ciphertexts, but you won't get your original plaintext back. The library probably warns you about this.

Comment: That means i have to give same modulus for both encryption and decryption ?

Comment: Yes, it's the public and private exponents (e and d) that differ. Your private key data contains every component that is necessary for the public key. Simply change the public key and see if it works.

Comment: i have used following open ssl command for getting private key data  - openssl rsa -inform PEM -text -noout < private_key.pem >pubkey.
txt. in that text file i am getting : modulus , publicExponent , privateExponent,prime1, prime2, exponent1,exponent2, coefficient. those things i have used for decryption

Comment: Yes, the private components might be consistent between themselves, but the public key does not correspond to the private key.

Comment: let me clear it. the steps i have followed . so that i can figure out the issues easily. 1) [ openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 1024 ] -> to get the private key. 2) next [ openssl rsa -inform PEM -text -noout < private_key.pem > pvtcom
ponent.txt ] -> to get the private componet.3) next [ openssl rsa -inform PEM -modulus -noout < private_key.pem > mod
ulus.txt ] -> To get the public key modulus. 4) the hexadecimal(Modulus) value got from 3 rd seto i used for encryption. 5) private componets i have used for decryption. please correct me if i am wrong in any place

Comment: I have never used the OpenSSL utility, so I cannot say whether you use it correctly.

Comment: Thanks artjom. Now my code is working . i have created new private components and public modulus and tried with cod and got working . thanks for the great help.